# IPython Shell Commands in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ipython

I'd like to use IPython's shell command feature `!` using Windows PowerShell commands, but many don't seem to work.  Specifically, when I launch IPython from PowerShell, I'd like to use the usual Powershell commands by escaping them with `!` like I do in bash.  But, e.g., `!cat`, `!ni`, `!rm` and `!cp` all return the error,

```
'<command>' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.
```

Why do these not work in PowerShell, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The IPython "!" syntax apparently invokes CMD.EXE, not PowerShell. You will need to explicitly invoke Powershell, possibly as `!powershell -command {<insert-your-command-here>}`, but the exact syntax, including any required quoting, will need to be a matter of trial-and-error if IPython doesn't document it. See [the MSDN page for PowerShell command line parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to switch the `!` syntax to PowerShell?  Also, if `!` invokes CMD, do you know why the commands work when running IPython from bash in MinGW?  Does IPython somehow know to switch to bash commands?

Comment: @bcf - To be more accurate, the "!" syntax apparently invokes the default shell for the environment - for Windows with no emulation, that will be CMD; for Linux or Linux emulation it would be the default shell, usually bash. I don't use IPython, so you'll need to check the docs to see if the behavior of ! can be altered.